# Coffescripts not receiving data from broadcasted message relay job

Tags: coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

Here's the code:

[How to ensure the javascripts/channels/chatrooms.coffee is loading and receive: (data) works? Console.log data is not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55545948/how-to-ensure-the-javascripts-channels-chatrooms-coffee-is-loading-and-receive)

I posted the problem the other day. It comes from a tutorial, but somewhere after continuing work on my project, I'm not sure where the bug came up,

But the message relay job posts on the server, and my config.yml has redis with redis up and running.

There have been similar bugs, but I've worked through those solutions and it's not enough. The received: (data) console log doesn't arrive in the js console of the browser.

The App subscriptions seem to all be in order according to the tutorial, I bet it's a really simple fix.

My messaging system still works, so it's not crucial to the project, but it's a difference of having the chat system work in realtime versus with a 4 second page-refresh delay.

Answer (score 0):

The last problem I had was not including jquery for my other coffeescripts, so I'm guessing the channels coffeescripts is probably a one line fix.